# How to define content size with CSS display:grid, rather than accommodate it

Tags: html, css, canvas

This [Codepen](http://codepen.io/blomcode/pen/ryewjb) illustrates the use of a grid dividing the page into 4 equal quadrants.  Each quadrant contains a canvas element. Enable "Experimental Web Platform Features" in Chrome for this to work.

The goal is to allow the canvas to resize itself based on the sizing and layout of the grid.
HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"><canvas></canvas></div>
  <div class="box"><canvas></canvas></div>
  <div class="box"><canvas></canvas></div>
  <div class="box"><canvas></canvas></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.wrapper { 
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( 2, 1fr );
  grid-template-rows: repeat( 2, 1fr );
}

.box {
  border: 2px solid #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

JS:

```
const els = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper div'))
const drawCanvases = function (els) {
  els.forEach(el => {
    const can = el.querySelector('canvas')
    can.width = can.parentElement.clientWidth
    can.height = can.parentElement.clientHeight-4


    var ctx = can.getContext("2d")
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height)
    ctx.font = "30px Arial"

    var mx = can.width/2
    var my = can.height/2
    ctx.fillText(`${can.width}px, ${can.height}px`,mx,my)
  })
}

window.addEventListener('resize', e => {
  drawCanvases(els)
})

drawCanvases(els)
```

The problem is that if the canvas sets its size to the parent div element as above, then the grid will never be able to make the column/row size any smaller.  Try the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/blomcode/pen/ryewjb), which displays the canvas size in the center of the element - you can drag and make the canvas elements grow, but you can never make them shrink.

Is this possible without manually recomputing the size we should set on the canvas?

Comment: you could also set in absolute the canvas into a relative div, so they do not come in the way while downsizing. Can you set a basic snippet or jsfiddle that shows your trouble :), could be usefull to demonstrate the idea

Comment: Here's a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/blomcode/pen/ryewjb) that illustrates the problem.  Based on @BrettDeWoody below.  Start with the window small, and note the size of each canvas printed in the middle.  Note that you can drag to increase window size and canvases get bigger, but you can never make them smaller.  :)  The point here is that I'm wanting to let grid do all layout and placement, and the canvas will just try to resize itself to its parent (obviously clientWidth/Height is not quite right here.)

Comment: I've edited the question to make the problem more clear, and provide a code example, which is heavily based on the example code provided by @BrettDeWoody below.

Comment: @GCyrillus - your initial comment of 14 hours ago (make the canvas position:absolute) appears to be the correct solution.  I'm porting an OpenGL UI to html/css/js and don't have a solid grasp on even the most basic layout rules with CSS it seems!  Thanks.  I don't think I can accept a comment as an answer, though.

Comment: sorry i was off line. You can answer yourself your question *(since you sorted out yourself  from a comment)* to make it usefull for somebody else :) .You might even accept it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, alluded to in a comment by @GCyrillus, is to set position:absolute on the canvas elements that are held within the relative divs:

```
canvas {
  position: absolute;
}
```

This [Codepen](http://codepen.io/blomcode/pen/LWRJwj) is identical to the one in the question, but adds the styling to the canvas so that the canvas size is not taken into consideration when sizing the grid rows and columns.

Remember that (as of this post) you'll need to enable Experimental Web Platform Features in Chrome (and similar in other browsers) to see this display:grid layout work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The four `div` elements will always have a width of 50% of the viewport width (since you're using `display: grid` with 2 columns). Instead of basing the size of the `canvas` element off their parent `div`, set the width of each `canvas` to 50% of the viewport width (or 50% the width of whatever their wrapper element is).

This demo will only work in Chrome if you have the Experimental Web Platform Features enabled.

```js
const els = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper div'))


  els.forEach(el => {
    const can = el.querySelector('canvas')
    var ctx = can.getContext("2d")
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height)
    can.width = window.innerWidth * .5
    can.height = 300
    ctx.font = "30px Arial"
    ctx.fillText(`${can.width}px`,10,50)
  })
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper { 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( 2, 1fr );
  grid-template-rows: repeat( 2, 1fr );
}

canvas {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div><canvas></canvas></div>
  <div><canvas></canvas></div>
  <div><canvas></canvas></div>
  <div><canvas></canvas></div>
</div>
```

Since you can't resize the SO window to see the effect here's a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/brettdewoody/pen/xqVdVJ) showing the same effect.

Comment: thanks!  This kind of solution "works", but it somewhat defeats what is gained by using a grid.  That is, if I'm going to hook window-resize anyway, I may as well do away with the grid(s) completely and just manually size/place divs absolutely.  I was initially hoping to completely rely on display:grid to layout and size multiple cells, and have the contained content automatically resize to fit grid-cell dimension.  I suppose this is exactly opposite of what most people want, but it seems like a reasonable use of a grid: to define content size, rather than accommodate it.

Comment: FF can also be used to play with grid ;) . 'as chrome you need to set experimental css flag on'

Comment: @ThomasBlom remember grid is still experimental, and bugs can be reported to help improve it ;)

Comment: Well, you could set the width of the canvas elements to 100% the width of their parent but percent widths on canvas can lead to strange results.